# What is the correct usage of My Location?

Tags: google-maps

My webapp is generating a link like the following that, when clicked, launches Google Maps on the iPhone (in this particular case) and Android (haven't tested that yet) and begins routing:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=My+Location&destination=5355+W+Main+St,Herriman,UT&travelmode=driving
```

That works perfectly about half the time, and the other half the time it interprets `My Location` as *around about the city I am in*, rather than *my precise location*. I was expecting that to always be interpreted as my current, precise location, where I am *right now*, with phone in hand.

A few notes and observations:

- Geolocation is enabled on the phone, else the `My Location` would never work - but it works perfectly and precisely about half the time.
- I have used Google Maps thousands of times on my phone. When I am navigating to various places, it always knows exactly where I am, within about 25 meters. It's not like it only knows my exact location about half the time; and yet when I launch the link above in my webapp (which launches into the Google Maps app, not a web page), from various places around the city, only sometimes does it interpret `My Location` as my precise current location.

When it fails to set the starting location as my current location, I have to go type an address of where I am (which is a big pain) before it can correctly navigate me to where I want to go.

Why doesn't `My Location` evaluate to my precise current location 100% of the time. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way I should be doing this? Should I entirely omit `My Location` and just put the destination address into the URL? And if so, how do I indicate *route me to that location from where I am now*?

Comment: Hello, what programming language are you using? What platform? From what I can see, you are just using the [Google Maps web app](https://www.google.com/maps) and not the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps). Also, I don't think this is a documented way of working with the Google Maps Web App. If you want some customizability in your program, I suggest you use the API.

Comment: I am using the API for other things, but for this use case, I just need to launch the Google Maps app, ready to navigate.